# Balzor server .net 7 css @media @page isolation

Tags: css, blazor, media

One component
Print.razor

```
 @page "/print"

    <h1>landscape</h1>
```

---

```
Print.razor.css
```

---

```
  @media print {
       @page {
          size: landscape;
       }
    }
```

---

Other component

```
   Print2.razor
```

---

```
 @page "/print2"

  <h1>portrait</h1>
```

---

### Print2.razor.css

```
@media print {
       @page {       
            size: portrait;       
        }
     }
```

---

I can't  isolate  @media in both component print portrait

Comment: Found soliution delete file Print2.razor.css replace file Print2.razor @page "/print2"
<style>
    @@media print {
    @@page {       
         size: portrait;       
    }
}

</style>


<h1>portrait</h1>

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.